# information regarding ndk-stack while using native android lib

Tags: android, android-ndk

I make some changes in external/webkit lib. after that Browser is crashing with signal 11.
I google to trace the problem. I find ndk-stack which is in ndk/ folder. after building ndk-stack tool, I check the command

> ./ndk-stack -sym out/target/product/generic/system/lib
>   -dump but nothing comes up.

I find another directory out/target/product/generic/symbols/system/lib

But I am not getting sufficient information after using ndk-stack.
My question is  does ndk-stack tool works on libs in external/webkit like native libs 
and there any other way to use ndk-stack tool, and which lib dir(out/target/product/generic/system/lib or out/target/product/generic/symbols/system/lib) is to pass to ndk-stack tool.

Answer (score 1):

You should run it like this:

```
adb logcat | ./ndk-stack -sym out/target/product/generic/system/lib
```